# Is there an existing speed control node to connect the robot_localization state estimator with the diff_drive_controller?

Tags: navigation, path, diff-drive-controller, velocity, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Indigo on a differential drive robot for indoor use (no GPS). The path is pre-determined and the velocity along the path is to be controlled. I believe that move_base node would be overkill and probably would not work in this case. Speed along path needs to be at a certain rate and if an obstacle is detected the unit will stop and send an alarm. I think a 2-D PID speed controller (linear and angular vel.) and a path planner that reads from the pre-planned path and provides the commanded 2-D speed is all that is needed. Is there an existing ROS node I could use or modify?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241045/is-there-an-existing-speed-control-node-to-connect-the-robot_localization-state-estimator-with-the-diff_drive_controller?/) by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-08-30**:
I think move_base could work. You just have to frame your predetermined path as a move_base global planner.

**Comment by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on 2016-09-05**:
I think the global planner goal format is a `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` message which is just a point and pose. I would need a goal with a format that includes a point (x,y) as well as a linear speed vector (vx, vy) defined for each waypoint.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-07-20**:
Did you ever figure this out? If so, can the question be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We couldn't find anything that could be used with only minor modifications so we developed a pure pursuit type of navigation control that provides angular and linear speed commands, which we are still testing.

---

Originally posted by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) with karma: 40 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0